# Array replaces values in blade

Tags: laravel

Hello i have this code in blade where i select dynamic product and amount and i insert it in an array but i have a problem that the values are not added but replaced, this is my code:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="products" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Product') }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="productOrder[product][product_id]" id="products" type="text" class="form-control @error('products') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="products"> @foreach($products as $product) <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option> @endforeach </select> @error('products') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span> @enderror
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="amount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Amount') }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="amount" type="text" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" name="productOrder[product][amount]" required autocomplete="amount"> @error('amount') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span> @enderror
  </div>
</div>
```

I have selected 2 products and insert 2 amounts for them but when i make `dd` i get this:

```
array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:39
  "product_id" => "2"
  "amount" => "20"
]
```

The result im trying to get is this:

```
array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:39
      "product_id" => "2"
      "amount" => "20"
      "product_id"=>"4"
      "amount" => "30"
]
```

I get the array fixed if i just delcare it `productOrder[][]` but then my result show up like this:

```
array:4 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:42
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "10"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "2"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "20"
  ]
]
```

But i need it with `nametag` so i can fetch it like this in `Controller`:

```
 foreach ($request->productOrder as $product)
        {
            dd($product['amount']);
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you putting it in the array?

Comment: @geertjanknapen at the `input` check the name of `inputs` like this: `<select name="productOrder[product][product_id]" id="products" type="text"`

Comment: @geertjanknapen if i just have it `name="productOrder[]"` the array is filled correct but i need both `product_id` and `amount` so i can fetch it with `foreach`

Comment: Make it like these `productOrder[1][product_id][]` and `productOrder[1][amount][]`. Then you can increment it every time you add the dynamic row. This will give you the result you required.

Comment: @iAmBorgy yes thats how i made it and it worked, thank you!

Comment: @laraCoder, good to know bruh!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use multiple inputs with the same input name. To make them unique you can use an index for each set of options.

```
@foreach($rows as $index => $row)
    <input name="product[{{ $index }}][product_id]"/>
    <input name="product[{{ $index }}][amount]"/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: but how can i apply your code to my `blade` as you can see its 2 different `div` one `select` the other `text`, should i put the `foreach` on top the 2 `divs`?

Comment: In your question you state that you want to select 2 products, how are you able to do that when you have only have one product select?

Comment: I have a button plus that adds the same code duplicate with JS that makes it dynamic to select x number of products and give x number of amounts

Comment: thats why i said i want to select 2 products because in the code i posted i can select only one but if i press the + button a new select tag will appear to choose a product and insert amount

Comment: That is your problem. Once you duplicate the HTML elements they will still have the same input names. That will not work as only one value with the same name can be used in a form. You can change the names with JS to something like `product[0][amount]` and `product[1][amount]` for every time you add a new row.

Comment: how can i insert an auto increment `++i` to `product[product][amount]` cant it be done something like `product[product . "++i"][amount]`  ?